# Aggregate functions in selection clause in relational algebra

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, relational-algebra

Is it possible to compare an attribute value to the value of an aggregate function in relational algebra? I would like to be able to say something like the following:

(SELECTION) clause= attribute1 > count(attribute2)

My teacher is sort of a stickler on only using methods described in class, however, if it is an established part of relational algebra I can argue him into accepting my answer as he is a mathematician first and fore most and couldn't take me stating he is restricting established parts of a system.

Comment: There is no one "relational algebra". What can be done in one depends on how it is defined. So give (a reference to) a definition of yours. Then show *some* example of using aggregation correctly in it or you are just asking us to rewrite your textbook. Don't expect people to understand syntax you made up; clearly say in words what you want to accomplish. PS The way you are using "count" is not the way to do typical relational algebra "aggregation" (via an operator called F or G). PS The point of doing a homework exercise is not to get an answer. It is to learn. How you get the answer matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a number of scientific papers that extend relational algebra with aggregation operators. However, I am not convinced that your teacher would accept your solution since he/she probably mentioned a book he/she is using in the class, so any extensions going beyond the book language might not be acceptable. Just in case you are really curious, please consider reading the following papers:

- G. Özsoyoğlu, Z. M. Özsoyoğlu, V. Matos. Extending relational algebra
  and relational calculus with set-valued attributes and aggregate
  functions, ACM Transactions on Database Systems 12(4), 1987
- A. Klug. Equivalence of relational algebra and relational calculus
  query languages having aggregate functions, Journal of the ACM 29(3),
  1982

Comment: Thanks for this info! I ended up foregoing inline expressions and referring to the values of the aggregate functions by name in the selection statement which I think will be acceptable but these look like interesting articles.